# OAuth redirect URL validation

Tags: redirect, oauth

I am working on an existing OAuth system in my office.
The previous engineer left and I am not really experienced in this OAuth system.

So I read a few documents about OAuth. I see that my office, as the OAuth server
is getting a redirect URL upon getting auth code from the client.

Then I see a validation which preventing a single character in the redirect URL.

Example:

1. https://m.clientname.us/oauth/redirect
2. https://pre.m.clientname.us/oauth/redirect

Number 1 would pass, but 2 does not

Do you guys think there is a reason the previous engineer making this validation? Is there a standard about it not to put a single character like sample number 2? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "single character", but the redirect URLs that your authorization server allows should absolutely be whitelisted to only registered redirect URLs. Any added subdomains or paths should cause the request to be rejected. Otherwise, an attacker can craft an OAuth request that looks valid to the end-user, but actually redirects them (with the authorization code) to their server.

Comment: are you trying to say that actually no specific constraint about the domain name as long as it is registered and match, yes?

Comment: Right, there's no limitation in the OAuth spec other than the redirect URI being a valid URI.